# Get file path from .xlsx file in clipboard

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to copy .xlsx files from the clipboard, but it's not in FileDropList as I assume it would be.

It seems to be a DataObject, but how would I continue from here?

```
Private Sub btnImport_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnImport.Click
    Try
        Debug.WriteLine(".....")

        If Clipboard.ContainsFileDropList() Then
            Dim filesArray = Clipboard.GetFileDropList()
            Debug.WriteLine(filesArray.Cast(Of List(Of String)).ToList())
        ElseIf Clipboard.ContainsText() Then
            Dim fileName = Clipboard.GetText()
            Debug.WriteLine(fileName)
        ElseIf Clipboard.ContainsImage() Then
            Debug.WriteLine("Image")
        Else
            Dim data = Clipboard.GetDataObject()

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Exceptions.LogAndShow(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: There are some suggestions on how to see what is actually in the clipboard in [How to access raw clipboard data on Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/378278/272824) That way, you'll be able to easily find out what it contains.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - this has indeed helped me to figure out it was a MemoryStream, thanks!